# Java and C# Regex not producing same result

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have part of a regular expression that I am trying to use to split sentences into words. As part of this, I would like to split patterns such as "word." into "word", ".". I do this by using a positive lookahead for the punctuation mark, and a negative lookbehind for a space character.

In Java, the following code accomplishes this:

```
Pattern test = Pattern.compile("(?=[\\p{P}&&[^']])(?<!\\s)");
test.split("word."); // returns ["word", "."]
```

However, when I tried it in C#, with the same pattern, it doesn't work.

```
Regex.Split("word.", @"(?=[\p{P}&&[^']])(?<!\s)");
// returns ["word."]
```

Why doesn't C# behave the same way here?

Comment: Why do you expect it to behave the same way?

Comment: The Java implementation must be wrong.

Comment: @ScottHannen: It's just a different flavor of regex.

Comment: Right. I expect Java and C# regex to be similar, but not exactly the same in all cases. In this case, I couldn't easily find the reason why they differed, so I asked.

Comment: @Matti: I know, I was just saying something stupid.

Answer (score 8):

That `&&` thing is Java specific regex syntax and will not work in .NET.

However I think you should be able to rewrite it in a simpler way in .NET as follows:

```
@"(?=[^'\P{P}])(?<!\s)"
```

It uses the `\P` character class which is the negation of `\p`, which gets negated by the `^` and ends up the right way round.

Comment: Another way to write it would be `(?=[\p{P}-[']])` (just the lookbehind part)